# Create dataframe with specific length

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

How can I create a new dataframe using pandas of 1000 length and assign values using for loop. I tried this way. But it doesn't work.

```
  f = {'ID': [],'CSE':[], 'Course Name':[]}
  ff = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
  for i in range(1000):
      ff.loc['173'] = [151, 'CSE']
```

It gives output like-

```
 *ID      *CSE   Course Name*   
 173       151      CSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
for i in range(1000):
      ff.loc[i] = ['173', 151, 'CSE']
```

Better and faster solution is create list of lists and then `Dataframe` by contructor:

```
#loop
L = []
for i in range(10):
      L.append(['173', 151, 'CSE'])

#list comprehension
#L = [['173', 151, 'CSE'] for i in range(10)]

ff = pd.DataFrame(data=L, columns=['ID','CSE','Course Name'])

print (ff.head())
    ID  CSE Course Name
0  173  151         CSE
1  173  151         CSE
2  173  151         CSE
3  173  151         CSE
4  173  151         CSE
```